# The package `' is defective

Tags: packages, documentclass-writing

I am trying to extend my class by supporting multiple paper sizes, and therefore adding some options by

```
\DeclareOption{a5paper}{% Paper size: 148mm x 210mm
%   \SBpaperAfivetrue
%   \SBpaperAsixfalse
}
```

My whole document as a MWE looks like

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{Liederbuch}[2016/02/04 version 1.00 Decoration and placement of songs]
\typeout{Book subclass: Liederbuch 2016/02/04 v 1.00}
% --- Class structure: declaration of options part
% --- 
% This class extends the book class
% Read all the documentclass options; pass them to book
\DeclareOption*{\InputIfFileExists{\CurrentOption.min}{}{%
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}}

% --- Class structure: execution of options part
% --- 
\ProcessOptions \relax

% --- Class structure: declaration of options part
% ---
\LoadClass{book}
%Page layout
%\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{gtrcrd}
\RequirePackage{stackengine}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\RequirePackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\RequirePackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

% --- Page size
% --- Option declaration for page size
\DeclareOption{a5paper}{% Paper size: 148mm x 210mm
%   \SBpaperAfivetrue
%   \SBpaperAsixfalse
}
```

imported in a document as

```
\documentclass[8pt,a6paper]{Liederbuch}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Hallo 2
\newpage
Test
\newpage
Test 3
\end{document}
```

If I leave the `\DeclareOption`, then I get the error

```
The package `' is defective.
It attempts to load `pdftexcmds' in the options section, i.e.,
between \DeclareOption and \ProcessOptions.
```

If I remove it, everything is fine.
If I move the `\ProcessOption` option after the declaration, I get even more errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have `\DeclareOption{a5paper}{...}` long after `\ProcessOptions`.

Comment: If I move it afterwards, then I get `! LaTeX Error: \RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section.`

Comment: You have to place it ***before*** `\ProcessOptions`

Comment: However, `\SBpaperAsixfalse` will throw an error, if `a5paper` is used.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I meant to move `\ProcessOptions` after the whole `\DeclareOption` block. Why will the latter one throw an error?

Comment: Declare options, process options, *then* load packages.

Comment: If I still want to use fancypagestyle, do I have to move it also downwards? How do I make sure, that my options set earlier have a higher priority?

Comment: @arc_lupus The position of `\ProcessOptions` is good (before `\LoadClass`); it's `\DeclareOption` that's at the wrong place.

Comment: @egreg Do you wanna write up an answer? Or do you have a dupe at hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct order should be

```
\DeclareOption{<option>}{<code>} % any number of them
\ExecuteOptions{<option list>} % optional
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{<class>}
```

After this line, other setup can be added, particularly addition of packages.